# AJAX response with undefined/object document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

1. My first question is I have this script that do a form exchange with my server. The server is able to read the form and send a response. When I try to print the response the below is show what I received.

   $('#myform').html(response); //there will be no response
   alert(response)//it always return me with [object Document].

So when i change it to the below, it show what I received:

```
$('#myform').html(response.xml);//it will return me with the xml value from my server
alert(response.xml)//normal xml value.
```

I can print out in eclipse web browser but not on any other browser(IE,firefox,chrome), it will return me with undefined.
Is there something wrong I did? my server will return me with html code:

```
<table><tr><img src=https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/--WAwSUUNAG8/UdOVEZvpnuI/AAAAAAAABIk/aV-NzcMN2zg/s800/g.gif></tr></table>
```

2. second question is how can I print the response as html(that mean the table) instead of plaintext.

Below is the java script code:

```
<script>
$(function() {  
  $(".button").click(function() {  
      var clin=$("input#client").val();
              var us=$("input#username").val();
              var dataString='client='+clin+'&username='+us;
      var res;
        $.ajax({  
              type: "POST",  
              url: "http://localhost:8080/services/web?wsdl/authen",  
              data: dataString, 
              success: function(response) {
                $('#myform').html(response);
                alert(response);
              }  
            }); 
            return false;   
  });  
});  
</script>
```

This is the server web service:

```
<xs:element name="authen">
     <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element name="client" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
               <xs:element name="username" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="authenResponse">
     <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element name="return" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
         </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

You debug that response to see the contents inside.

Please try

```
dataType:'html',
success : function(data, status, response) {
    var obj = $("<div/>").html(response.responseText);
    $('#myform').html(obj.find("ns:return").html());
    alert(response.responseText);
}
```

### and take a look at [jQuery API Document](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) too.

Added the dataType.

Comment: the alert(respond.responseText) replied with this <ns:authenResponse xmlns:ns="http://webpackage"><ns:return> <table><tr><img src=lh6.googleusercontent.com/--WAwSUUNAG8/UdOVEZvpnuI/AAAAAAAABIk/…;

however the form $('#myform').html(obj.find("ns:return").html()); did not show anything.

Comment: I added the dataType parameter. If you use only alert, you can try alert(obj.find("ns:return").html()), and alert(obj.find("table").html()) too.

Comment: both this alert(obj.find("ns:return").html()), and alert(obj.find("table").html())
return me with undefined. could it be the server response?

Comment: can the response not in plain text? cause the response is still in plain

Comment: Take a look at [jQuery Ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), dataType can be xml, json, script, or html

Comment: And if possible, cut the xml stuff off. Just only the html code.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is rather unclear, it seems to me that you're getting undefined as your response and that that's your problem. Maybe try changing

```
"http://localhost:8080/services/web?wsdl/authen"
```

to

```
"/services/web?wsdl/authen"
```

Or changing

```
data: dataString,
```

to

```
data: {
  client: clin,
  username: us
}
```

Comment: I follow as you mention but,both alert(response) and (#myform).html(response) replied me with "[object]" as the response.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying the above question. 1st question is that my response from server is send out, but when i received with AJAX at the above code, it always give me as [object], undefined or [object document]. The response from server is something like this <table><tr><img src=https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/--WAwSUUNAG8/UdOVEZvpnuI/AAAAAAAABIk/aV-NzcMN2zg/s800/g.gif></tr></table>

Comment: Is it not supposed to be an object? Is the response supposed to be a string? That's odd.